# Keep shell open after program is run with Notepad++ RunMe plugin

Tags: php, notepad++

I want to run php programs in the windows terminal from notepad++. I researched and tried various solutions but ended up choosing the runMe plugin which works fine, except it closes the terminal after execution so I can't see any output. I've looked at the options and can't find a setting to change this. Any ideas plaease?

Comment: Curious to know why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't just open the commandline (cmd.exe) and run "**php -f filepath**"?

Indeed you have to add PHP befor to the PATH var.

**Edit1:** NppExec could also help you. https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/

Your problem is that your commandline window closes after the php process is done. To avoid that you need to run you script from a command line window. 
So the correct way to go is: Start cmd.exe -> run php with the above named parameters. You could achieve that by batch scripting.

**Edit2:** You can try the following command:

*cmd /k Z:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"*

You dont have to add the full path to the PHP executable if you have add it to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I'm looking for ease of execution. I've tried putting `cmd /k php $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)\$(FILE_NAME)` into the run dialog, but I get `Could not open input file: C:\Program C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++>` which suggest current path is the notepad++ path. What should I put in the run dialog to make this work please? I know once it's correct I can assign a keyboard shortcut, which is what I'm after.

Comment: I've edited my answer (look at Edit2).

You dont need to add FILE_NAME here because it'S already included in the FULL_CURRENT_PATH. You also have to specifiy the "-f" switch for PHP so it expects a file and not plain source code.

Comment: Great that works. I used `cmd /k php.exe -f "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` because php is in my path. Out of curiosity, what is the nuture of that statment? Is it an external DOS command? Or something to do with Notepad++? Particularly, is `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` from npp functionality or Windows?